# Are files in /tmp cleaned up by the operating system?

Tags: ubuntu, redhat-enterprise-linux, solaris, aix

I have a script that generates log files that I place under `/tmp`
I run it on Linux RedHat, Ubuntu, Solaris and AIX.

I'm wondering I have to clean the logs periodically by myself (e.g. after 14 days) or may be the operating systems cleans it by itself since it resides in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 3):

If your OS does not clean /tmp automatically, install [`tmpreaper`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/tmpreaper) or [tmpwatch](https://fedorahosted.org/tmpwatch/).  They can be set to run as cronjobs so the cleaning is automatic.  They are easily configured to follow your preferences for what to keep, what to clean, and when to clean it.

On a debian-like system, run `apt-get install tmpreaper`.  The configuration file is typically `/etc/tmpreaper.conf`.

How can you find out if one of these is already installed?  One way is to run `locate tmpreaper` and `locate tmpwatch` and see what turns up.  If they are installed, you may want to check their config files (under `/etc/`).  With debian-like systems, one has to make a manual change to `/etc/tmpreaper.conf` to enable `tmpreaper` to run under `cron`.

Normally, all files in `/tmp` are deleted on every reboot.  Consequently, programs like `tmpreaper` are only needed on machines with long up-times.

Comment: Thank you. How do I know if the machine clean it automatically? Do you mean that I have to check on crontab?

Comment: @user1762109 Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `df -T` and see if `/tmp` is mounted as a separate file system. If it is not, there is a high possibility that it will not be cleaned out automatically. For example, on my CentOS 7.1 box, /tmp is just a part of the root (/) file system and contains old files from before last reboot.

On my laptop `df -T` gives me:

```
Filesystem           Type        1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
dev                  devtmpfs      1912020          0    1912020   0% /dev
run                  tmpfs         1919840       1008    1918832   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-root ext4        118698260   89524160   23121444  80% /
tmpfs                tmpfs         1919840     168044    1751796   9% /dev/shm
tmpfs                tmpfs         1919840          0    1919840   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                tmpfs         4194304        168    4194136   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1            ext4            95054      59743      28143  68% /boot
tmpfs                tmpfs          383968        104     383864   1% /run/user/1000
```

All tmpfs are in RAM and cleared on a reboot.

If `/tmp` is not mounted separately, you can add an `/etc/fstab` entry like this one:

`tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=nG 0 0`

This will create a RAM file system **n** Gigs in size. Be sure to put a lower number than the amount of memory you have available.

---

As an alternative to [user3163621](https://superuser.com/users/332256/user3163621)'s, you can just put a crontab entry like this one:

`@reboot rm -rf /tmp/* /tmp/.*`

Answer (score 0):

Linux, ubuntu and Solaris will clean your /tmp on reboot.  But not AIX, file in /tmp will remain there.

You can setup a cronjob to do it for you as root

> 0 1 * * * find /tmp -atime -14 -exec rm {} \;

At 1h00 am, each day, it will find and remove files that were last accessed 14 days ago.  or you can put -mtime -14 for the last modified files.